# Noun for word that means waiting for one last step

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a noun that represents the scenario of waiting for a final event/approval, or having everything done except for the last step.

So if you have status markers like, *Completed*, *Assigned*, *Started*, *Stopped*, our word would indicate we are waiting for a last step.

Comment: *Penultipending*? Hee hee.

Comment: "Penultimate" means next-to-last.

Comment: @DanBron Hah, That might be the closest we are going to get!

Comment: "Pending final approval (or whatever other event)" is the usual way it's stated.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think one word is gonna cut it.

If I were you, I'd label it something like `Finalized, pending approval`, and we could call that state `finalized` for short,  internally, purely to distinguish it from the next stage rather than to be semantically accurate.

When it's done, you could call it "Done", "Completed", "Finished" and so on..

PS - We have a saying in Hindi: "The elephant is through, the tail remains"

Answer (score 4):

Many ticket-management systems use steps such as "Assigned, Started, Finished, Delivered, Accepted"

In that paradigm, the word you're looking for could be *Delivered* - which means that the task has been completed and submitted for final approval.

If, instead, your task is waiting for another step, it's not finished, it's *on hold*.

Comment: I was thinking *Submitted*, myself.

Answer (score 1):

You ask for a noun, but then you use status markers that are verbal modifiers. I am not sure if you really need a noun.

Two phrases come to mind:

*on the cusp*

One of *Oxford Dictionaries Online's* definition of *[cusp](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cusp)* is

> A point of transition between two different states:
>   those on the cusp of adulthood

Similarly *[on the brink](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+brink)*

> on the verge of doing something; almost to the point of doing something. *I was on the brink of selling my car to make ends meet when the tax refund came in the mail.*

*thefreedictionary.com*